# How to mock DbConnectionStringBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, moq, system.data

Here's a simple code which reproduces an exception:

```
var csbMock = new Mock<DbConnectionStringBuilder>();
var csb = csbMock.Object;
csb.ConnectionString = "data source=.;integrated security=true";
Debug.WriteLine(csb.ConnectionString); // System.NullReferenceException in System.Data.dll
```

Stack frame consists of only one line: `at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.get_ConnectionString()`

My goal is to simply be able to get/set `DbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString` property of the mock. What's the problem here?

Comment: You do realize that you actually do not need to mock it. You could create an instance of it and use it as desired.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right.

Comment: There are no knock-on effects of using the class as is

Comment: True. I've started this approach with a thought it is abstract, the same as `DbConnection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no need to mock the [DbConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

There are no knock-on effects of using the class so you could create an instance of it and use it as is

```
var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
//Set the connection string directly
builder.ConnectionString = "data source=.;integrated security=true";
//or add the parts needed to create a connection string
builder.Clear();
builder.Add("integrated security", true);
builder.Add("Data Source", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

This line fixed the problem:

```
csbMock.CallBase = true;
```

Some magic happens inside `DbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString` setter. It calls virtual members which are overriden by a proxy and then this NRE hapens in getter.